# AutoHotKey dropdown list which opens links on ME

Tags: autohotkey, microsoft-edge, hyperlink, dropdownlist, open

Trying to create AutoHotKey with drop down list to open internet links (for company). As I created, noticed errors and mistake, that I cannot fix it.

First it runs whole script and I have around 80 links, and for the last one I have to wait 80 seconds to open it, secondly sometimes in show hidden icons area it opens multiple AutoHotKey scripts...

As well I tried to go with function Run, msedge.exe "page link" " --new-window" - but it cuts half of the link, and it does not work... so I came up with clipboard + paste. Maybe someone could help me in this case where do I make mistake? AutoHotKey version 1.1.35.00

```
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
; DropDownList:
; Gui, Add, DDL, gAction vChoice Choose1 w200, Page one|Page two| Page three| Page four
; ListBox:
Gui, Add, ListBox, gAction vChoice w200 h60, one|two|three|four
return

; Press F1 to show the gui:
F1::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseMove, 40, 50, 0
Gui, Show, x0 y0, Actions
return


Action:
Gui, Submit ; or

    if (Choice = "Page one")
    Run, msedge.exe
    Sleep 1000
        clipboard := "page link"
    Send ^v
    Send {enter}

    if (Choice = "Page two")
    Run, msedge.exe
    Sleep 1000
        clipboard := "page link"
    Send ^v
    Send {enter}

    if (Choice = "Page three")
    Run, msedge.exe
    Sleep 1000
        clipboard := "page link"
    Send ^v
    Send {enter}

    if (Choice = "Page four")
    Run, msedge.exe
    Sleep 1000
        clipboard := "page link"
    Send ^v
    Send {enter}
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
My_links =
(
autohotkey questions - Super User | https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey
windows-10 questions - Super User | https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10
command-line questions - Super User | https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line
)

Loop, parse, My_links, `n
{
    page_name := StrSplit(A_LoopField," | ").1
    list .= page_name  "|"
}

Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Add, ListBox, gAction vChoice w300 h60, %list%
return

; Press F1 to show the gui:
F1::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseMove, 40, 50, 0
Gui, Show, x0 y0, Actions
return

Action:
Gui, Submit
Loop, parse, My_links, `n
{
    If InStr(A_LoopField, Choice)
    {
        page := StrSplit(A_LoopField," | ").2
        Run, msedge.exe "%page%" --new-window"
        break
    }
}
return
```

Comment: Replace all `%` by **`%**  in the links